# NoSuchMethodError Arquillian's TestRunner.passed

Tags: java, testng, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

When trying to run an Arquillian (1.1.8.Final) test, it fails with a huge stack trace with this as a description:

```
Error launching test at http://127.0.0.1:9080/test/ArquillianServletRunner?outputMode=serializedObject&className=pacakges.UserHandlerTest&methodName=registerUserTest. Got 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Looking up the console, I found an error stack trace:

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] UT005023: Exception handling request to /test/ArquillianServletRunner: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestResult.passed()Lorg/jboss/arquillian/test/spi/TestResult;
at org.jboss.arquillian.testng.container.TestListener.getTestResult(TestListener.java:82) [arquillian-testng.jar:]
at org.jboss.arquillian.testng.container.TestNGTestRunner.execute(TestNGTestRunner.java:55) [arquillian-testng.jar:]
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.executeTest(ServletTestRunner.java:160) [arquillian-protocol.jar:]
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.execute(ServletTestRunner.java:126) [arquillian-protocol.jar:]
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.doGet(ServletTestRunner.java:90) [arquillian-protocol.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_25]
```

It seems that the code `TestListener` is trying to run a method that does not exist (`TestResult.passed`). I was looking into it, and it does not exist. Tryed the same thing with JUnit and the result was the same.

Diving into it:
Arquillian's TestNG container code for [TestListener](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-core/blob/master/testng/container/src/main/java/org/jboss/arquillian/testng/container/TestListener.java)
and
Arquillian's TestNG container code for [TestResult](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-core/blob/597373b680ddd361a8763ccc931033d9cb9c43e5/test/spi/src/main/java/org/jboss/arquillian/test/spi/TestResult.java)

Trying to run the tests with previous version failed all the way to version 1.1.4.Final.
Version 1.1.3.Final - ALL PASSED!!

I don't understand how it works for anyone...

Comment: I have the same problema with 1.1.3.Final, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

try to add the class in your deployment : .addClass(TestResult.class)
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Update your **Arquillian Core Platform** jars to the latest release

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
  <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

I faced the same problem because I used Arquillian bom for WildFly which comes with JUint dependencies. I changed the JUnit jars to TestNG jars and tried to run test written in TestNG. Because the arquillian core was not compatible with the TestNG, I got the exception that you have got.